# Unsubscribing from job alerts results in Invalid request

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, email

Clicking the *Unsubscribe from this email* link (from a job alert email) leads to a page that says *Invalid request*. Will this be addressed?

Comment: Can you please forward me the email you received? Find my email on my profile. Thanks!

Comment: @g3rv4 Hello, the email is gone but I have emailed you the precise url address. I will delete this post as I think it doesn't belong on meta.

Comment: @Ron it does belong here, don't worry about it; we're investigating

Comment: There's no need to delete the post. Meta is the place for people to report issues with /jobs as well and if other people experienced the same, they'll be able to chime in :) I'll let you know once we have more details (probably tomorrow).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sooooo... this is fun. Due to technical details with how Stack Overflow and /jobs are hooked together it would appear that an account you requested for deletion last month didn't get deleted on the /jobs side. As a result we sent an email to your deleted account and when you tried to unsubscribe from it Stack Overflow didn't know what to do.

I've removed that legacy account and we have an item on our backlog to make this work more generally. Apologies for the inconvenience.